# Color filter formatting in Android

Tags: android, parsing, hex

I'm trying to set the color filter of a button based on events going on outside the GUI.
I found the way to set it to a fixed color like:

```
_button.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFF000000,hexInteger));
```

Where hexInteger is the tint of the button.
My problem is parsing the hexInteger, which I'm attempting to do like this:

```
int[] hexSequence = {0xFF,0x00,velocityFactor,0x00};
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(hexSequence.length);
for (int i = 0; i < hexSequence.length; i++)
            {
                sb.append(hexSequence[i]);  
            }

int hexInteger = Integer.parseInt(sb.toString(), 16);
```

For a value of HexInteger == 255 I get the value 626009424 (0x25502550) as opposed to the expected 4278255360 (0xFF00FF00)

What did I not understand about the suggested method?

Regards
/M

Answer (score 0):

You have found a really complex way to do it. 
I suppose you can do just

```
int hexInteger = (0xFF << 24) | (velocityFactor << 8);
```

Comment: This gives me a value for hexInteger == 0.. changing to int hexInteger = (0xFF << 24) | (velocityFactor << 8); gives me the right color.

Comment: oh yes, i made really horrible mistake somehow